# Heroku + Facebook + NodeJS: cannot find module 'OAuth'

Tags: facebook, node.js, heroku, oauth-2.0

I am new to NodeJS so this is probably an easy fix. However I was not able to find the solution with my current comprehension level.

I cloned the heroku-facebook-nodejs template from Github, and am trying to do some testing in the development environment on my local server. I am using nodejs version 0.6.10

https://github.com/heroku/facebook-template-nodejs

I modified the package.json as the following:

```
{
  "name":        "facebook-template-node",
  "version":     "0.0.1",
  "description": "Template app for Heroku / Facebook integration, Node.js language",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "0.4.3",
    "everyauth": "0.2.18",
    "express": "2.5.2",
    "facebook-client": "1.3.0",
    "facebook": "0.0.3",
    "node-uuid": "1.2.0",
    "socket.io": "0.8.7",
    "connect": "1.8.5"
  }
}
```

I removed the following:

```
require.paths.unshift(__dirname + '/lib');
```

and replaced

```
var socket_manager = require('socket_manager').create(io);
```

with

```
var socket_manager = require('lib/socket_manager').create(io);
```

and then ran npm-install -d to install the modules locally.

When I run node web.js, I get the following error:

```
system-process:hollow-cloud-1974 ericjang2004$ node web.js 
The "sys" module is now called "util". It should have a similar interface.

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Cannot find module 'oauth'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:332:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Eric/Desktop/hollow-cloud-1974/node_modules/everyauth/lib/modules/oauth2.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
```

I am not sure how to proceed. Any tips? I read that Heroku uses an older version of Node, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "oauth": "0.9.5" to your dependencies in package.json, so it looks like:

```
"dependencies": {
    "ejs": "0.4.3",
    "oauth": "0.9.5",
    "everyauth": "0.2.18",
    "express": "2.5.2",
    "facebook-client": "1.3.0",
    "facebook": "0.0.3",
    "node-uuid": "1.2.0",
    "socket.io": "0.8.7",
    "connect": "1.8.5"
  }
```

and run `npm install -d`

Answer (score 1):

running `npm install whatever --save` instead will ensure that the module gets added to the package json.

you would do `npm install whatever --save-dev` if its a development dependency...